# DataTable.DefaultView.Sort not sorting properly when sort by DateTime Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, datetime, datatable

I have a data table in which there are four columns as per below:

```
DataTable Quarters = new DataTable();
Quarters.Columns.Add("QuarterId", typeof(int));
Quarters.Columns.Add("Quarter");
Quarters.Columns.Add("StartDate", typeof(DateTime));
Quarters.Columns.Add("EndDate", typeof(DateTime));
```

After populating data using code I want to sort the data table rows as per the start date field which is of type `DateTime`.

To do so, I have written the following line of code:

```
Quarters.DefaultView.Sort = "StartDate";
```

But after getting the data I am not getting the proper output. The date is treated as string.

My output is as follows after sorting the data (the below image is of watch window not my grid):

[image]

What should I do to get the records sorted correctly?

Comment: There are many options - if You are doing this sort once at start - i suggest to sort Your collection before populating your datagrid or whatever it is

Comment: `Quarters = Quarters.DefaultView.ToTable()` Use this after `Quarters.DefaultView.Sort = "StartDate";`

Comment: Hello @CodingDefined it is working fine. You can add it as answer so that I can mark as correct one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Iget confused by another issue.

to do this staff Create a new Class CustomDateClass which implements IComparable Interface and has a property DateProperty typeof(DateTime)

Then Override the CompareTo method to compare DateTimePromerty.

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is CustomDateClass)
            {
                DateTime dt = ((CustomDateClass)obj).DateProperty;
                return dt.CompareTo(DateProperty);
            }
              throw new ArgumentException("not CustomDateClass");
        }
```

For your DataTable change DateLine by this:

```
Quarters.Columns.Add("EndDate", typeof(CustomDateClass));
```

Comment: Are You sure about this ? If it would be treated as a DateTime then datagrid would sort it correctly, culture doesn't matter, I think that DataGrid is parsing this DateTime to string and that's what causes the problem. I think it would be better to create collection from this DataTable and sort it inside this collection. It would have additional advantage - binding capabilities

Comment: @MajkeloDev Any progress there ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll show You different(proper I think) way to to this.
First let's create a class for this data:

```
public class classNameGoesHere
{
    public int QuarterId { get; set; }
    public string Quarter{ get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate{ get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate{ get; set; }
}
```

Now, in Your class which is resposible for working on this data - let's handle this.

First create a list of Your data class.

```
List<classNameGoesHere> listName = new List<classNameGoesHere>();
```

Now let's populate this list with easy LinQ query.

```
listName = from x in Quarters.AsEnumerable()
           order by x.StartDate descending // sorting is beeing done here
           select new classNameGoesHere
           {
               QuarterId = x.field<int>("QuarterId"),
               Quarter = x.field<string>("Quarter"),
               StartDate = x.field<DateTime>("StartDate"),
               EndDate = x.field<DateTime>("EndDate")                  
           };
```

Now You can bind this to Your DataGrid.ItemsSource.
Actually if it's possible - it would be better to do this without any DataTable. Instead of puplating DataTable - populate Your data in a list like i showed You.(Propably just a little bit of refactoring code).
I Hope It will help.